# How to make a specific element scrollable, but not the whole page?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm trying to make a single div scrollable.
I've set `overflow-y` to `"scroll"` but instead of the `<div>` becoming scrollable when I put extra items in the `<div>`, the whole page becomes scrollable like this:

[image: scrollable page screenshot]

How can I make that `<div>` (chat-history) scrollable so that it is possible to view all the messages without changing the whole page?

```css
* {

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {

    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 4fr 15fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px calc(100vh - 65px); 
}
.navbar {

    grid-column: 1/4;
    background: #223;
}
.main-panel {

    display: none;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #223;

}
.screen {

    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #223;
}
.left-panel {

    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #223;
}
.buttons {

    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background: #223;

}
.button {

    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center; 
    padding: 15px;


}
#chat-button {
    width: 25px;
    height: auto;

}
.messages {

    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    
}
.message {

    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    
}
.sender {

    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.message-mine {

    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    background-color: #321;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;

}
.my-messages {

    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    
}
.chat-history {

    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bruh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <p>Hello</p><br>
        </div>
        <div class="main-panel">
            <p>bro</p><br>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="button">
                <div class="chat-button">
                    <a>
                        <img id="chat-button" src="chat-dots.svg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="screen">
            <p>bro2</p><br>
        </div>
        <div class="left-panel">
            <div class="chat-box">
                <div class="chat-history">
                    <!--  -->
                    <div class="my-messages">
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--  -->
                    <div class="messages">
                        <!--  -->
                        <div class="message" id="message1">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <!--  -->
                        <div class="message" id="message2">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="message" id="message3">
                            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
                            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="chat-sending-area">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
 .chat-box{
    height: 100%;
}
.chat-history {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

set ".chat-box" and ".chat-history" height to "100%" so it fits its parents container height while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give your div some height to fix this issue.

For example

```
.chat-history{
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like the chat-history part to be responsive and not have a fixed height. I tried to use percentages but that didn't work. could you please help me with that? I tried to make the chat-box div a grid but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you need chat-history to be responsive, then give it's parent some height. Even giving 100% to parent should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make your left-panel scrollable.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 4fr 15fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px calc(100vh - 65px);
}

.navbar {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  background: #223;
}

.main-panel {
  display: none;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: #223;
}

.screen {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: #223;
}

.left-panel {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: #223;
}

.buttons {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: #223;
}

.button {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

#chat-button {
  width: 25px;
  height: auto;
}

.messages {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.message {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.sender {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.message-mine {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #321;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.my-messages {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.left-panel {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar">
  </div>
  <div class="main-panel">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="chat-button">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="screen">
  </div>
  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="chat-box">
      <div class="chat-history">
        <!--  -->
        <div class="my-messages">
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>

          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!--  -->
        <div class="messages">
          <!--  -->
          <div class="message" id="message1">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <!--  -->
          <div class="message" id="message2">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
          <div class="message" id="message3">
            <span class="sender">
                                me:
                            </span><br>
            <span class="content">
                                testing...
                            </span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-sending-area">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, however this didn't work because there are several other things I want to put in the (left-panel) div and also the (textarea) in the chat-box should be stationary. Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to work with the overflow scroll you need to swt the `height` or `max-height` of the container. Try using the one below style in your stylesheet.

```
.chat-history {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Working Fiddle.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 4fr 15fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px calc(100vh - 65px);
}
.navbar {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  background: #223;
}
.main-panel {
  display: none;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: #223;
}
.screen {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: #223;
}
.left-panel {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: #223;
}
.buttons {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: #223;
}
.button {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
#chat-button {
  width: 25px;
  height: auto;
}
.messages {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
.message {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.sender {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.message-mine {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #321;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.my-messages {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
.chat-history {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="main-panel">
    <p>bro</p>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="chat-button">
        <a>
          <img id="chat-button" src="chat-dots.svg" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="screen">
    <p>bro2</p>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="chat-box">
      <div class="chat-history">
        <!--  -->
        <div class="my-messages">
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>

          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="message-mine" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--  -->
        <div class="messages">
          <!--  -->
          <div class="message" id="message1">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <!--  -->
          <div class="message" id="message2">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="message" id="message3">
            <span class="sender"> me: </span><br />
            <span class="content">
              testing...
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-sending-area"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the main page is still scroll-able here. could you please help me with that?